# How to implement chart.js in Angular2

Tags: angular, chart.js

I'm using Angular2-rc4 with angular-cli webpack and would like to implement a chart.js library.

I've installed chart.js to my project using:

> npm install chart.js --save

Then I've tried to import the chart.js in my component:

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import 'chart.js/src/chart.js';
declare let Chart;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent {

  chart: Chart;

}
```

But I get an error in console log:

```
[default] /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bridge/src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts:12:9 
Cannot find name 'Chart'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you got solution?

Answer (score 32):

I had a similar issue, it turned out I was referencing an old example.

First, as you've already correctly done, install the library using NPM:

```
npm install chart.js --save
```

Then, in your component, import the library:

```
import Chart from 'chart.js';
```

To get up and running with a quick example, have a look at the example code in the Chart.js [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-creating-a-chart) or see my example below.

---

### dashboard.component.ts

```
import Chart from 'chart.js';
import { ViewChild, Component, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-dashboard',
    template: '<canvas #donut></canvas>'
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('donut') donut: ElementRef;

    constructor(
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        let donutCtx = this.donut.nativeElement.getContext('2d');

        var data = {
            labels: [
                "Value A",
                "Value B"
            ],
            datasets: [
                {
                    "data": [101342, 55342],   // Example data
                    "backgroundColor": [
                        "#1fc8f8",
                        "#76a346"
                    ]
                }]
        };

        var chart = new Chart(
            donutCtx,
            {
                "type": 'doughnut',
                "data": data,
                "options": {
                    "cutoutPercentage": 50,
                    "animation": {
                        "animateScale": true,
                        "animateRotate": false
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I added a second parameter of null to @ViewChild: @ViewChild('donut', null)

Answer (score 22):

In the template don't forget to enclose *canvas* in a *div*.
If *canvas* is a direct child of custom directive in dom, then chart might not load.

```
<div><canvas id="myChart"></canvas></div>
```

I have wasted lot of time in finding this issue.

Comment: Do you know why that is the case?

Answer (score 5):

Here is the best module out of few on npmjs:

[angular2-chartjs](https://github.com/emn178/angular2-chartjs)

Then you can use it like this in your module:

```
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-chartjs';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ ChartModule ]
  // ...
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

And in html template:

```
<chart [type]="type" [data]="data" [options]="options"></chart>
```

Don't forget to fill it with data ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using webpack you may try adding the chart.js file (*or the minified version*) to the **entry** property as follows:

```
...
entry: {
      'chartJS': './node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js',
      // Other mappings
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem using `<p-chart>`  primeNG.

Just add this in your index.html:

```
<script src= "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.bundle.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

And that´s it, you don´t have to import in your typescript.

I found that in chart documentation

-then use a Chart.js CDN.

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Chart.js

Answer (score 1):

I tried. this works for me easy to implements
 https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/