# Chart.js Show labels on Pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

I recently updated my charts.js library to the most updated version (2.5.0).
This version doesn't show the labels on the chart.

I have an example of working one on fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/g6fajwg8 .

However, I defined my chart exactly as in the example but still can not see the labels on the chart.

Note: There are a lot of questions like this on Google and Stackoverflow but most of them are about previous versions which is working well on them.

```
var config = {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: [
              1200,
              1112,
              533,
              202,
              105,
            ],
            backgroundColor: [
              "#F7464A",
              "#46BFBD",
              "#FDB45C",
              "#949FB1",
              "#4D5360",
            ],
            label: 'Dataset 1'
        }],
        labels: [
          "Red",
          "Green",
          "Yellow",
          "Grey",
          "Dark Grey"
        ]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            position: 'top',
        },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Chart.js Doughnut Chart'
        },
        animation: {
            animateScale: true,
            animateRotate: true
        }
    }
};

window.pPercentage = new Chart(ChartContext, config);
```

[image]

Answer (score 104, accepted):

It seems like there is no such build in option.

However, there is special library for this option, it calls: "[Chart PieceLabel](https://github.com/emn178/Chart.PieceLabel.js)".

Here is their [demo](https://emn178.github.io/chartjs-plugin-labels/samples/demo/).

After you add their script to your project, you might want to add another option, called: "pieceLabel", and define the properties values as you like:

```
pieceLabel: {
    // mode 'label', 'value' or 'percentage', default is 'percentage'
    mode: (!mode) ? 'value' : mode,

    // precision for percentage, default is 0
    precision: 0,

    // font size, default is defaultFontSize
    fontSize: 18,

    // font color, default is '#fff'
    fontColor: '#fff',

    // font style, default is defaultFontStyle
    fontStyle: 'bold',

    // font family, default is defaultFontFamily
    fontFamily: "'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif"
}
```

Comment: I use it and it works very well. It changes it's values on filtration and do it with pretty animations.

Comment: Is there any way to use this plugin in Angular2. I am using chart js in my angular 2 project : https://stackoverflow.com/a/42556725/2879146 I am importing plugin but it's not working. There's no error on console.

Comment: @HiteshKumar It doesn't look like it was made as a module. Downloading the file using npm also includes a min.js file under build/. I copied that to my public/assets/js/vendor/ folder and referenced the file from there.

Comment: piece label is a great library and should be part of the basic functionality

Comment: I would by now recommend to use https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels. It's an official package from Chart.JS and seems to be get better support.

Answer (score 25):

Use data labels plugin
https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/

HTML integration

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.7.0"></script>
```

***must be loaded after the Chart.js library!***

Your code will be like this

```
options: {
        plugins: {
            // Change options for ALL labels of THIS CHART
            datalabels: {
                color: '#36A2EB'
            }
        }
},
data: {
   datasets: [{
            // Change options only for labels of THIS DATASET
            datalabels: {
                color: '#FFCE56'
            }
   }]
}
```

You will see the values of datasets as a label by default if you want to override this. e.g by label

```
options: {
        plugins: {
            datalabels: {
                formatter: function(value, context) {
                    return context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex];
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-datalabels) and set the options like this

```
 options: {
                plugins: {
                    datalabels: {
                        formatter: function (value, context) {
                            return context.chart.data.labels[
                                context.dataIndex
                            ];
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
```

it will render the labels text