# How to show the data labels without hovering the mouse on the bubbles

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I created a bubble chart using Chart.js, but the data label of each bubble will only be displayed when the mouse hovers over the bubble. How to show the data labels of all the bubbles by default (i.e., without hovering a mouse on top)?

```
new Chart(document.getElementById("stock-chart"), {
    type: 'bubble',
    data: {
      labels: "Africa",
      datasets: [
        {
          label: ["Stock 3, Stock 4"],
          backgroundColor: "rgba(255,221,50,0.2)",
          borderColor: "rgba(255,221,50,1)",
          data: [{
            x: 0.1,
            y: 5.245,
            r: 15
          }]
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Chart title',
        fontSize: 28
      }, 
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{ 
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: "Return",
            fontSize: 25
          },
          ticks: {
              fontSize: 20
          }
        }],
        xAxes: [{ 
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: "Risk",
            fontSize: 25
          },
          ticks: {
            fontSize: 20
        }
        }]
      },

      tooltips: {
          callbacks: {
              label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                  var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label;
                  return label;
              }
          }
      }

    }
});
```

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42164818/chart-js-show-labels-on-pie-chart

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using the chartjs-plugin-datalabels(https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels). Specifically, remove the `tooltips` section in `plugins` and add the following section:

````
        datalabels: {
            anchor: function(context) {
                return 'center';
            },
            align: function(context) {
                return 'center';
            },
            font: {
                weight: 'bold',
                size: '15'
            },
            formatter: function(value) {
                return value.label;
            },
            offset: 0,
            padding: 0
        }```
````