# JavaScript in typescript error new() ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm wokring on this code :

```
....
this.charts.push(new Chart(document.getElementById("chart0"), {..}
...
```

Html:

```
<ion-row><canvas id="chart0" style="width:512px;height:320px"></canvas>
    <canvas id="chart0" style="width:512px;height:320px"></canvas>
    <canvas id="chart1" style="width:512px;height:320px"></canvas>
  </ion-row>
```

And I have this error :

```
Cannot find name 'Chart'.
```

What could be the error?
I have to use an ngModel on char0 ? I have no idea how to do it!

Comment: Have you imported `Chart`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39084296/how-to-implement-chart-js-in-angular2

Comment: @noggin182 how to import Chart?? I have only this : import 'chart.js';